GithubAction Split String Variable Value or How to use NodeJS Output
I'm trying to make a Github workflow.
My action is using a Node script to update a file and i need the new version in my other steps.
I've tried to get the value of my script
  - name: Update File
    id: update_file
    run: echo $(npm run patch-file)

echo is giving
> patch-file > node patch-file.ts file patch 0.0.16

file and patch are arguments of my script.
The 0.0.16 value is outputed with this line in the script
console.log(version);

How can i retrieve the value 0.0.16 in the Github action for use in later steps?

In your node script, you need to write in the GITHUB_OUTPUT, it seems it's a file?!
here is what you do to output a variable
const fs = require('fs');
const newVersion = '1.0.0';
fs.writeFileSync(process.env.GITHUB_OUTPUT, `new_version=${newVersion}`, 'utf8');

Here is the steps in the GitHub Action
  - name: Update File
    id: update_file
    run: npm run patch-file

  - name: Use the new version in future steps
    run: |
      echo "The new version is ${{ steps.update_file.outputs.new_version }}"


I think you can set custom variables into $GITHUB_ENV like this:
- name: Set Github ENV variables
    shell: bash
    run: |
       # Define
       testVar='testVarValue'
       # Set
       echo "testVar=$testVar" >> "$GITHUB_ENV"

This testVar variable will become available through $GITHUB_ENV in the next CI step

You can use this way to set the output of npm output to env
name: TEST
on: push
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Set Hello
      run: echo $VERSION=$(npm run patch-file) >> $GITHUB_ENV
    - name: Test
      run: echo $VERSION


i get an error with this while doing the $VERSION=$(...) >> $GITHUB_ENV.
Run echo $VERSION=$(npm run patch-file) >> $GITHUB_ENV
Error: Unable to process file command 'env' successfully.
Error: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'name')
